# Why is ヒョウ the 音読み of 氷?

Tags: readings, history

氷/冰 has [pronunciations bīng/bing1/빙 (bing)/băng in Mandarin/Cantonese/Korean/Vietnamese](https://cjkv-dict.com/?search=%E6%B0%B7), yet the Japanese 音読み is ヒョウ. Is there a process that explains this sound change, or does this come from another dialect? (Or is it a case of 慣用音?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL/DR**

This is absolutely regular and continues the pronunciation of mid-8th century Chang'an Late Middle Chinese. However, there are details (such as the corresponding go-on) which are not exactly clear.

**Long-ish**

The Early Middle Chinese pronunciation for 冰／氷 is 筆陵切 ([fanqie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie)), that is, *ping* (Baxter reconstruction). That is already enough to understand both *h-* and *-u* of the modern pronunciation: *p > ɸ > h* is a general sound change in the history of Japanese, while the final *-ng* of Chinese was, due to the absence of anything similar in Nara and Early Heian Japanese, borrowed as a nasalized *-ũ*, which later lost nasality.

The interesting thing is why the vowel in the middle is *-o-*. The modern reading ヒョウ, if we assume the *-ng* ending, can go back to actual ヒョウ (*pyoũ*), or ヒャウ (*pyaũ*), or maybe ヘウ (*peũ*). The version with ヘウ would seem to make more sense, assuming the borrowing took Chinese *ping* with a slightly more open vowel, similar to *peng*. But this is not corroborated by the data: any Japanese dictionary says ヒョウ is the historical reading, and thus claims that Chinese *ping* was borrowed as something akin to *pyoũ*.

In order to check whether that is a 慣用音 reading, we can start by checking other characters with the same final *-ing*. In the terminology of the rhyme tables, that's rhyme 133 蒸 (*-ing/*-wing*). It contains a lot of frequent characters, such as: 承 (*dzying*) ジョウ・ショウ, 徴 (*tring*) チョウ, 勝 (*sying(H)*) ショウ. As we see, this is not a fluke: the *-ing* ending is indeed taken in Japanese as *-you*, in many unrelated words.

Why would that be? Well, the Early Middle Chinese reconstructions we started with are based on the convenience of the *Qièyùn* dictionary, which represents the literary pronunciation of late 6th century and is also a compromise between Northern and Southern features, not corresponding to the actual pronunciation of anyone except maybe some very orthoepically minded literati. Meanwhile, the go-on borrowings typically represent the pronunciations of Korean elite of around 7th century, while kan-on is a wholesale borrowing of Late Middle Chinese of the Tang capital, Chang'an, from mid-8th century, which was quite peculiar and is not apparently ancestor to any modern dialect.

The easiest explanation would thus be that the Chang'an pronunciaiton which was the basis for kan-on rendered *-ing* as something closer to being borrowed as *-yoũ*.

Edwin G. Pulleyblank, in his *Lexicon of Reconstructed Pronunciation: in Early Middle Chinese, Late Middle Chinese, and Early Mandarin*, provides a Late Middle Chinese reconstruction *piəŋ* (level tone), which is perfect: Old Japanese vowel *ö*, phonetically [ə], is one of the two sources of modern Japanese *o*, so a borrowed Chang'an *piəŋ* would become *pyəũ* in Japanese and then, indeed, give ヒョウ with historical spelling also ヒョウ.

The only remaining mystery is why the go-on reading also shows *-yoũ* despite apparently borrowed (through one of the languages of Korea) from a stage of the Chinese language when the pronunciation was closer to *ping* (which would lead to modern Japanese **ヒュウ). But with the irregularity of go-on in principle, this might be not discoverable. Perhaps, the enforced go-on reading was normalized after kan-on, to which there are many precedents. [As in neither of the characters we considered (氷, 承, 徴, 勝) the go-on is in current use, the go-on for such characters could be lexicographically fictitious!] Perhaps, the borrowing was ultimately from a dialect where the shift to *-iəŋ* came earlier. Perhaps, the intermediate Korean Peninsula language phonology was somehow involved.

*Literature:*

- Pulleyblank, Edwin G. *Lexicon of Reconstructed Pronunciation: in Early Middle Chinese, Late Middle Chinese, and Early Mandarin.* UBC press, 1991.
- Frellesvig, Bjarke. *A history of the Japanese language.* Cambridge University Press, 2010.
- Miyake, Marc Hideo. *Old Japanese: A phonetic reconstruction.* Routledge, 2003.
- Baxter, William H. *A Handbook of Old Chinese Phonology.* De Gruyter Mouton, 1992.
- Various 漢和辞典 dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you - great detail. The vowel originally being nasal definitely helps explain the jump from /ŋ/. After posting this question it occurred to me how common the ŋ → -u change is, e.g. [陽](https://cjkv-dict.com/?search=%E9%99%BD) yáng → ヨウ.

Comment: Note that while in modern Japanese the final ン may sound a better match for -ng than for -n, the Portuguese materials show that as late as 16th century ン was pronounced [n].

Comment: +1: I am curious why some words retain (?) the bilabial sound /b/ such as 病 while others have changed to /h/. Is it due to the difference in the original sound in Chinese?

Comment: But Portuguese speakers pronounce a syllable-final /n/ as a nasal vowel.

Comment: Indeed, we can see in the 1603 _Nippo Jisho_ that words spelled with ん in the Japanese are spelled consistently with ⟨n⟩ in the Portuguese orthography of that time.  See [this page](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFJAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q&f=false), for instance, where a word like 寒巌【かんがん】 is spelled as ⟨cangan⟩.

Comment: Over time, I've noticed that Japanese _goon_ often correspond with modern Min Nan pronunciations.  For 氷, modern Min Nan Hokkian is _peng_ and Teochew is _bian¹_, corresponding more closely to Old Japanese _pyō_, where we would expect that more open vowel in the Chinese.  As you note, it is puzzling that the oldest kana spellings show ひよう instead of the expected へう.

Comment: The pronunciation of ン as [n] is, I believe, shown by the (productive at least until Edo period) process of renjō (観 かん + 音 おん > 観音 かんのん), which would be somewhat strange assuming velar [N] at the end of the first element (something like かんごん being more expected as medial g was pronounced ŋ up to middle 20th century).

Comment: @aguijonazo The retention of [b] in the beginning merely means that the Middle Chinese consonant was [b]. As EMC b > Chang’an pɦ, words starting with b can have b- or h- in Japanese based on go-on vs. kan-on; words with original p (or ph) can only have h. Also, EMC m > Chang’an b in many cases, hence examples like 文 ブン, while EMC mjun.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi As I said, I’m not sure old go-on spellings would exist in this case. Go-on was reformed heavily at least twice, with the Buddhist masters making it more predictable from kan-on and then the kokugaku scholars matching it to LMC rhyme tables exactly. Also, unlike kan-on, the actual go-on was never systematic or covering all the existing characters, so it just might be that until Chang’an 氷 happened not to be borrowed to Japanese.

Comment: Re: 連声, see also 天皇【てんおう】 → 天皇【てんのう】.  As counterpoint, we still have 雰囲気【ふんいき】 and 反映【はんえい】, making me wonder if there's something specific about the phonetics of ん+お.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135476/discussion-between-alexander-z-and-eirikr-utlendi).

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 雰囲気 is just a recent, Meiji word. Portuguese have things like 三谷 さんにゃ, 因縁 いんねん, and even 人間は にんげんな.

Answer (score 7):

I am no expert but let me try.

The /h/ sound in Japanese used to be bilabial just like /b/ and /p/. In modern Japanese, ふ /fu/ is still pronounced with the bilabial fricative [φ] (rather than the labiodental [f]). I suppose Japanese in old times heard the Chinese sound that would become /bi/ in modern Maridan as something like ふぃ (or ふ itself may have been closer to ぶ or ぷ).

As for /ng/, since Japanese has no such thing as a syllable-final consonant, people must have heard it as an added vowel like う.

Something like ふぃう eventually became ひょう. Before the small kana were introduced in orthography, this sound was written as ひよう or ひやう.

Although there are exceptions, as a general rule, the syllable-final /n/ in Chinese corresponds to ん in Japanese, and /ng/ to a prolonged vowel.

- 賓 [bīn]: ひん
- 品 [pǐn]: ひん
- 病 [bìnɡ]: びょう
- 餅 [bǐng]: へい
- 金 [jīn]: きん
- 京 [jīnɡ]: きょう, けい

This is one exception I can think of off the top of my head.

- 瓶 [píng]: びん

Comment: Fascinating - thanks. I note [餅](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A4%85) has a 呉音 of ヒョウ, too.

Comment: One note about historical pronunciations: at the time of borrowing for most kanji, Japanese was in the Old Japanese stage.  Most linguists agree that modern Japanese //h// and //f// (the はひふへほ kana) all started with a //p// sound at that time, with the 濁点【だくてん】 or voiced version naturally starting with //b//.  So there would not have been any ふぃう realized as //fiu// when first borrowed.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - Thanks. I was not sure if it was completely plosive or somewhat in between plosive and fricative. So I borrowed the letter ふ as the closest modern equivalent.